# MEDIUM BLACK CIRCLE always black on some devices

Tags: html, css, unicode

I'm using the Unicode Character 'MEDIUM BLACK CIRCLE' aka:
**&#9899**

and then changing its color. It works fine on most of my devices, but on my android phone and some collegues PC's (same pc brand and browser) it is always black and not *#009FDA*.

```
<span style="color:#009FDA;">&#9899 </span>
```

How do solve this?

Solved!

solution(font-awesome):
`<i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#009FDA;" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

I'm still very interested in why this happend if anyone knows..

Comment: There's a very interesting reason this is happening: some browsers and mobile OS's replace this symbol with an emoji (which cannot be colored): http://emojipedia.org/medium-black-circle/

Comment: You may be better off using a bullet character and enlarging its size, or creating a small circle in HTML/CSS (with background-color and border-radius: 50%).

Comment: Well, it's called *black* circle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options

**Option 1:Unicode charecter**

Use Unicode charecter. it works

```css
body{
  font-size:15px;
  line-height:15px;
}
```

```html
<span style="color:#009FDA; ">&#9899 </span> 
<br/>
<span style="color:#009FDA; font-size:250%; height:15px; ">•</span>
```

**Option 2:Shape round using border-radius** (works fine in all browsers)

Class for circles which has `border-radius:50%;` and same width & height

```css
span.circle{
  height:10px;
  width:10px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color:#009FDA;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class='circle'></span>
```

**Other options: You can use [Font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/), svg or images**

Comment: Also, it's not because you use the unicode character in unescaped form, but because you used a *different* unicode character (`&#x2022;` to be exact), which happens to not have this problem.

Comment: Other options include images or SVG.

Comment: Yah but both are same shapres right... thats why i used them.

Comment: @GolezTrol yes u r right. thanks, it worth mentioning about other options

Comment: Why didn't i think of font-awesome.. I already have that in my system.

solution:
`<i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#009FDA;" aria-hidden="true">`

I'm still very interested in why this happend if anyone knows..